# Is there a jquery combo box that looks like the one used in google services?

Tags: jquery, combobox, html-select

I'm looking for a jquery based altenative to the standard HTTML **select** component (the classical combo box).

There are many jquery components that seems to be suitable for me, but none of these are capable of doing all that things at the same time:

- Gain focus where the user press tab on the keyboard
- Be a strong read only (no cursor blink in the field)
- Keystrokes act in the same way of the html select
- up/down arrow keys open the dropdown and navigate

In little words, i need a component that have exactly the **same behaviour** of the html select, but that features full skin capabilities.

It seems that the one used in the google services perfectly fit my needs.

Is this component public? Is there a component that do the same things?

Answer (score 0):

This one is really good http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/blog/jquery-image-dropdown but unfortunately doesn't do all stuff you need.